# Can I use hydraulic cement under tile?

Tags: tile

Can I use hydraulic cement as a top surface to fill in gaps in cement board in a cold/ hot outdoor weather area? This will be under the tile.

Comment: What kind of gaps? That seems important information to have before we answer.

Comment: I have used hydraulic cement around toilet & water pipes (hot and cold)  coming up but as it is expensive compared to mortar I usually use mortar. To fill cracks and level sheet to sheet differences. It would probably work ok though.

Comment: I needed to make a bull nose form so I scored the cement board and formed it around a 2in pipe. The form is solid but now I need to fill in the grooves left by the scoring that run the length of the work. I dont want the form to fail or tile to pop off .

Answer (score 0):

You really need some kind of uncoupling membrane to prevent the crack from transferring through to the tile. Like kerdi or ditra.